# 2 layered Bevel using Python Script (Blender 3.2.1)

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, bevel

I'm trying to write a python script that created two layers of bevel on an object. I'm working with Blender 3.2.1 and the attached version of Python.

```
    #Bevel 1
    mod_bevel = base_Obj.modifiers.new(type='BEVEL',name='edge1')
    mod_bevel.limit_method = 'WEIGHT'
    mod_bevel.width = 0.5
    mod_bevel.segments = 1
    #Bevel 2
    mod_bevel2 = base_Obj.modifiers.new(type='BEVEL',name='edge2')
    mod_bevel2.limit_method = 'ANGLE'
    mod_bevel2.angle_limit = 0.523599
    mod_bevel2.width = 0.2
    mod_bevel2.segments = 4
```

The first bevel works, but the second does not. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Overlap problem? `mod_bevel2.use_clamp_overlap = False`

Comment: how come "Bevel 1" doesn't work for me? You mean "Bevel 2" works but not 1.